# Javascript is not executed on website with HtmlUnit and PhantomJS

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs, htmlunit

I was trying to get the html source of a webpage first with HtmlUnit, than with PhantomJS, but both are failing me. The page source I get is packed with Javascript, it seems it's not being executed. I dont' really understand what is happening. The HtmlUnit version I tried:

```
webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=cats&view_all=1");
webClient.close();

System.out.println(page.asXml());
```

The phantomJS version:

```
File phantomjs = Phanbedder.unpack();
DesiredCapabilities dcaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
dcaps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
dcaps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, phantomjs.getAbsolutePath());
dcaps.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");

driver = new PhantomJSDriver(dcaps);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=cats&view_all=1");
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Would be really grateful if someone could help me out here. Thanks.

Comment: If all you want is the static source, why don't you simply use an HTTP lib, or JSoup? It'll be far quicker, easier, and more reliable.

Comment: No, I want the Javascript generated source to get image links.

Comment: OK, might be worth clarifying the question. Also, please report any errors / output you get. `seems it's not being executed`is not very helpful.

Comment: Well, no errors are really given, HtmlUnit gives this warning: WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'. PhantomJS only outputs some general info.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't overthink this.  On Firefox, install the (web) [developers toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/).  Click View Source --> Generated source.

Comment: With view source it also only shows the javascript that will generate the images. It's weird, because the browsers load the images correctly. If I "inspect element", the image href's are there. I just don't understand why HtmlUnit doesn't process that Javascript(doesn't throw errors).

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the JS is simply not executed and no errors thrown.

Comment: Would be cool if someone tried and succeeded to get images from https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=cats&view_all=1.

Comment: Take a look in firebug. My hypothesis is that you have a Javascript error.